# What's the different between a linear fit and an average derivative?

Tags: derivatives, linear-regression

I've been asked to calculate a linear fit (of data that is approximately linear) using a certain database but the closest thing I can do is calculate the average derivative (over time) e.g. I have 10K points that again when plotted look approximately linear. I'm looking for a way to explain in plain english the difference between these two calculations.

My understanding that if the data is perfectly linear then they are the same but when it starts "curving" then the average derivative is more sensitive and therefore a worse fit.

Sample data (see picture)
x,y,derivative
(1,1,N/A)
(2,2,1)
(3,3,1)
(4,5,2)
(5,8,3)

Average derivative: 1.75
Slope of linear fit (Excel) 1.7

[image]

Comment: Why can't you do a linear regression to get the best linear approximation?  I wouldn't expect that to have all that much to do with any derivative of the function...

Comment: yeah I don't have that option. if I could do a linear regression I would but I can't. are you saying that the average derivative doesn't = the slope for linear data? I think they're equal when the data is linear but for nonlinear data there are discrepencies

Comment: I would expect minimal connection for a general function.  The derivative depends on purely local data, while the best linear fit is entirely global.  Obviously, if you have more information about the function which generates the data you can say something more exact.

Comment: ok I have time series data that is roughly linear and I have a lot of it like 10K data points so that's what I'm trying to draw a line through not a general function

Comment: If you have all that data, then it is a trivial matter to do the linear regression, so do it!

Comment: Of course, the closer the data is to a linear function, the better the derivative will be as a match.  But general data is seldom that friendly.